# Could not find class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder

Tags: android, sdk, noclassdeffounderror

Today I have a strange error, strange because the app worked some day ago and I don't change anything, I had also updated Android SDK and eclipse.

> 05-20 08:03:14.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1925):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
>
> 05-20 08:03:15.918: E/dalvikvm(1716): Could not find class
>   'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder', referenced from
>   method com.me.app.ObjReminder.setNotification

Why have I this error? How can I solve it?

**EDIT:** Thanks all, I solve checking 'Android Private Libraries' in 'Order and Export' tab. But I don't understand why the check was disappeared

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. Check the link. Right click on your project. goto properties. choose java build path. choose order export tab. choose Android Private Libraries. Clean and build

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990 helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever we update our SDK the default support api gets auto updated.

So the previous referenced support library would get obsolate.

You just need to open project properties and update referenced libraries.