# R.java not genereated in a New eclipse project

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn to develop Android applications and I'm using eclipse, I Installed the android SDK and eclipse and I was able to make a couple of basic examples but suddenly I updated the SDK with the lates reviews and eclipse is not generating the R.java anymore, I read a lot of forums with the same problem but all responses are releated with errors one the code and errors on the xml's but I just create a new project with all defaults and not touching any line or any configuration and I don't have the R.java so I can't run the project I've clean the project 100 times and I reinstalled everything a couple of times but nothing works, so totally frustrate, I change from my Windows 8 PC to my MAC and I found exactly the same problem. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. check the link and try. right click on your project. goto java build path. order export tab. make sure Android private libraries is clicked. Also make sure you have installed sdk build tools from android sdk manager. clean and build.

Comment: Thanks!! The installed skd build tools was missing now it's working fine