# xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" gets added to all my layout objects causing errors

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

At some point after updating all my ADT tools and Eclipse, all my XML files error when I open them

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` gets added to every layout object (root object like how I originally set it, and nested RelativeLayouts and LinearLayouts and FrameLayouts)

this causes errors in that XML file and I have to manually remove them, even with find and replace this is unnecessarily and tedious to do when I just want to look at an xml document

why is this happening, how can I prevent it

Comment: @blackbelt I have the newest everything, no nightlies though. I was hoping that would fix all the bugs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan did not help, I had to do that stuff for some other things after updating to ADT 22, but this problem is still here for me

Comment: strange coz i have not come across anything like this before. Curious to see the solution posted by others. will wait for an asnwer

Comment: once i also faced same problem

Comment: @user123 do you know what caused it or what exactly made it go away?

Comment: i didn't got any proper solution therefore i reinstalled it

Comment: Have you discovered the solution to this?  I just updated my eclipse and now I've started getting this also.

I tried the clearning lint markers and it was of no help

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your lint errors

Right click your project goto-> Android Tools... -> choose Clear Lint Markers