# Getting system error in android will running google map app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to just display a google map in my app. I had generated the API key and placed it in to the main.xml file. But the problem is when run the app it opens a mapview but doesn't show the default map it only display blank map view. and in log cat it show following error
please help me

thanks in advance

```
05-22 17:25:45.982: I/MapActivity(1131): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
05-22 17:25:45.982: E/MapActivity(1131): Couldn't get connection factory client
05-22 17:25:46.282: D/gralloc_goldfish(1131): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-22 17:25:47.492: D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 9% free 2920K/3184K, paused 19ms+20ms, total 125ms
05-22 17:25:47.942: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:47.942: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:47.962: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:47.962: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:47.962: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:47.977: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:47.982: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:47.982: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:48.372: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:48.372: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:48.382: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:48.382: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:48.382: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:48.382: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:48.392: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:48.392: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:48.822: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:48.822: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:48.822: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:48.832: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:48.832: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:48.832: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:48.832: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:48.832: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:49.282: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:49.282: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:49.282: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:49.292: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:49.292: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:49.312: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:49.312: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:49.312: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:49.742: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:49.742: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:49.742: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:49.752: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:49.762: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:49.762: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:49.762: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:49.762: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:50.204: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:50.204: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:50.212: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:50.212: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:50.212: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:50.224: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:50.224: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:50.232: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:50.662: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:50.662: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:50.672: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:50.682: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:50.682: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:50.682: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:50.682: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:50.692: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:51.062: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:51.062: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:51.072: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:51.072: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:51.082: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:51.082: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:51.082: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:51.082: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:51.452: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:51.452: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:51.452: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:51.462: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:51.503: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:51.503: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:51.503: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:51.503: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:51.902: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:51.902: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:51.912: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:51.922: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:51.932: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:51.932: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:51.932: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:51.932: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:52.362: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:52.362: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:52.362: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:52.362: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:52.372: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:52.372: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:52.372: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:52.372: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:52.755: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:52.762: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:52.762: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:52.762: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:52.782: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:52.782: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:52.782: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:52.782: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:53.152: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:53.152: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:53.162: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:53.162: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:53.172: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:53.172: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:53.182: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:53.182: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 17:25:53.632: W/System.err(1131): IOException processing: 26
05-22 17:25:53.632: W/System.err(1131): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-22 17:25:53.642: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
05-22 17:25:53.642: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-22 17:25:53.642: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-22 17:25:53.652: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-22 17:25:53.652: W/System.err(1131):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-22 17:25:53.652: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using deprecated Android API v1.

Please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index

Comment: @ivy You can't have `IOException` in Google Maps javascript API v3 ;)

Comment: So i guess I don't configure app properly if it don't undestand when I switch between v2 and v3...