# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo, Didn't find class on path: /data/app/

Tags: android

I am trying to run a project that is running on some other machine. I would like to add that i have recently updated my ADT. I get the following error when trying to run my project:

```
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tv.pg/com.tv.pg.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tv.pg.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.tv.pg-2.apk
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tv.pg.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.tv.pg-2.apk
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-23 09:31:15.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1633):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this