# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have updated **Android SDK** to **API Level-17**. As a result, I am getting **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader**. I have included "android-support-v4.jar" in "libs" folder and referenced to it via. "Java Build Path", but still same error.

Any help or guidance to resolve the issue will be well appreciated.

Comment: this seems to be a common problem with updating adt to rev 22. if you have updated check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: Hi blackbelt, thanks for quick reply. I am having ADT-22.

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan for valuable advice, your advice worked for me.