# Unfortunately the app has stopped working in android after one week

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed this android application that was using the Google maps and has been working well but after a week it is not running. It is giving this error. "Unfortunately the app has stopped working" I have uninstalled and installed it again and the same error shows up. please help

Comment: post some code. also did you update adt to rev 22?

Comment: @kevin kaburu add tag related to API V3 or V2..and other related tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127 try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check Google map **Web-Service** in Browser, I think it also not work too.

Because Google Map API is **changed**, now it **Version-2**

Check out this **link :** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/