# R cannot be resolved (Another)

Tags: android, resolve, sony

Well - it would seem over the past several days, I've read almost every threat here about the subject, but none have worked!

I've just started to develop a new app and as soon as the project was created, the error appear.

As a last resort only, could some kinda fellow (or gal :) ) kindly observe to see if they can spot an issue which may be hindering my applications function?

MainApplication.java;

```
 package com.sony.thirdtest;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.sony.smallapp.SmallAppWindow;
import com.sony.smallapp.SmallApplication;

public class MainApplication extends SmallApplication {
private Configuration mConfig;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mConfig = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    SmallAppWindow.Attributes attr = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attr.minWidth = 200;
    attr.minHeight = 200;
    attr.width = 400;
    attr.height = 300;
    attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_RESIZABLE;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attr);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainApplication.this, R.string.hello, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected boolean onSmallAppConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    int diff = newConfig.diff(mConfig);
    mConfig = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    // Avoid application from restarting when orientation changed
    if ((diff & ActivityInfo.CONFIG_ORIENTATION) != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onSmallAppConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

main_activity.xml;

```
<manifest  
package="com.sony.thirdtest" 
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >   


    <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />

    <service 
        android:name="MainApplication"

        android:exported="true" >

        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>
```

Can I please make clear that this has been a last resort,

Kind regards.

Comment: is there any errors in your resource files. cross check once? did this happen after updating adt to rev 22?

Comment: I'm running the latest version of ADT, so I would assume so.

The only files I have in the recourse folders are ic_launcher.png - in the drawable folders.

No other errors in the program. Just these 2 about "R"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this. if it crashes i suggest you post logcat info of the crash

Comment: <service android:name=".MainApplication"" />//missing a . Also are you sure you want a service instead of activity?. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Import com.sony.thirdtest.R;

Answer (score 0):

This is were the error might be.  findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

declare button this way and try

```
            public class MainApplication extends SmallApplication {
             private Configuration mConfig;
             Button button1;

                  @Override
                 public void onCreate() {
                button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                      {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "your message", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It missing manifest balise at end file. And it is better to put xmlns attribut at first. Try this:

```
<manifest  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sony.thirdtest" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
              android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >   


        <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />

        <service 
            android:name="MainApplication"

            android:exported="true" >

            <intent-filter >

                <action android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is late but i'm facing with that problem too many times and i want to share my opinion. The problem is about your resource files. Check your layouts, values etc. Adt will always say that `import android.R` or `import com.yourpackage.R`. Do not regard that quick fixes.