# GCM NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to execute an example with GCM, it was working a week ago, but I have updated the last revision (22), and it's not working anymore. I'm working with 4.2.2. I have the gcm.jar in the folder /libs and I updated the Google Cloud Messaging for Android as well.

I guess that my manifiest is right because it was working a week ago... So, what could it be wrong? I guess that it should be work,, I have tried in a device and in a AVD with the same result.

The exception is:

```
05-23 20:05:36.986: E/AndroidRuntime(1287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 20:05:36.986: E/AndroidRuntime(1287): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
05-23 20:05:36.986: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):     at com.rooms.activities.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:67)
```

I guess that I could be something that I have to configurate in the properties in my project,, but, I don't figure out what it could be wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this

Comment: In the updated ADT(Above ADT 17) you have to put jar files inside libs folder and not lib. So make sure that you put gcm.jar file inside libs and not lib folder.