# My android projects are marked with red "X"

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was using Eclipse Indigo and the Content Assist was working properly.
But when I installed Eclipse Indigo, I found that Content Assist ctrl+space is not working. 
What I did is, creating new work space and imported the old project I created into the new work space created in Eclipse juno.

Now, the Content Assist is working but all the projects I imported are marked with red "X"
and this is my problem.

**Console Output**:

```
[2013-05-24 22:40:12 - TestCreatOptionMenu] Unable to resolve target 'Google    
Inc.:Google APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:12 - WeatherFragment] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google   
APIs:8'
[2013-05-24 22:40:12 - Vortex2] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:12 - URLTagger] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:12 - URLHandler] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - TouchEvent] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google   
 APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - ToggleButtonDemo] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - TimeDateTest] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google    
APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - ThumbnailCameraPicture] Unable to resolve target 'Google   
Inc.:Google APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - Text_Image_Switcher] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - TestXML] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - TestOnKeyPressed] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - TestLocation] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google   
APIs:10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - Test9] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - Test4] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
[2013-05-24 22:40:13 - Test3] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
```

Comment: Look at the "problems" window and let us know what the problems are...

Comment: Launch the Android SDK Manager and check if all required SDK platforms  and Google APIs are installed, particularly for Android 2.3.3 (API 8) and Android 2.2 (API 10)

Comment: if you have updated adt to rev 22 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127