# Unable to resolve errors on sliding menu example with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Hi I am a newbie to android and I am trying to run the Sliding Menu Example but i am getting so much errors

I have downloaded the package from here:
http://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

and setup the actionbarsherlock

Also followed the instructions listed over here: http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-slidingmenu-android-library-and-example/

and i am getting the following errors:

[image]

- I am using Eclipse 22.0.0 and recent version of Android SDK

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this. also check if there is conflict of jars. both sliding menu and actiobarsherlock may have the android-support-v4.jar

Comment: @Raghunandan android-support-v4.jar conflicts have been resolved already

Comment: ydo you have any errors from what i see Cannot resolve Fragment Activity to FargmentChangeActivity. Something is wrong here. R.java will not be generated if there are errors in resource files

Answer (score 1):

try this...

- add actionbarsherlock library to slidingmenu library
- in your project libraries, use only sliding menu library, not
     actionbarsherlock.
- delete the android support library in libs
     folder in slidingmenu library, and in libs folder in your project
- and clean all projects, and try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated SDK means,

select project->right click->go to properties->order and export>select Android Private Libraries. Click Ok.

Clean the project and run it.

Comment: I have done it already and I was getting the same errors on previous version of sdk I had earlier

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspect for such errors is the minSdk/targetSdkVersion of your Android project. Try minSdkVersion of 7 and targetSdkVersion 17 (latest as of now). That is, your AndroidManifest.xml should be having this line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

And also, from project properties, set Android 4.2 (latest as of now) as the target. Project properties -> Android -> target:4.2

That should solve it. But, if you are still getting errors (on account of different versions of SlidingMenu), experiment with higher minSdkVersion.