# App crashes on New google android maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have added `google maps v2`. They use `Google play services`. It seems from the rating that most of the users don't have updated Google play services thus getting crashes when they try to open the application..

Is there any way that we can make part of code the lib of google play service so they won't get crash...

Would love to find out any solution

Comment: how are you referring google play services in your library project? Can you explain in detail

Comment: @Raghunandan properties>Android>Adding play services as library

Comment: Got it. Now what is the problem that you are facing? Any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5395

Comment: Seems that those who haven't updated google play services crash at  mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView))
                    .getMap();      most probably classDef not found error. I don't remember now. Same error u will get on a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user doesn't have `Google play services` you can show dialog to get it

```
// Getting Google Play availability status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());


//there are other "status" values as well, you can check according to your need

// Showing status
if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

    int requestCode = 10;
    ialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
    dialog.show();

}else{ // Google Play Services are available 

    // get map and play with it
}
```

where `ConnectionResult` is:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
```

Comment: That's a cool thing but is there any way we can add the lib sort of thing so its automatically support my maps?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar check the link in my answer.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar if you have updated your adt to rev 22 check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: @MuhammadUmar have you updated you adt plugin to rev 22. i suspect that is the case and that is causing classdef not found error

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)
```

Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than the one required by this client.

Returns
status code indicating whether there was an error. Can be one of following in ConnectionResult: SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.

Check the developer site under the topic **Check for Google Play Services**

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html