# "The import net cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have an Android project in Eclipse that previously had one library imported, zbar. And now something peculiar happened when I added a second library, one which I put together myself. At first, the project wouldn't build because of android-support-v4 mismatch. So I updated the minSDK of my application project to reflect the one in my library. That seems to have worked.

Next, I wanted to make use of my new library, so I created an object of a type defined inside it, and thus had to import the code. What happened next was Eclipse started to complain about one of the imports to zbar.

```
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
```

And what i don't understand is, it says "The import net cannot be resolved", and only the word "net" is underlined in red. As if it didn't see the period following "net". What's going on here?

I have tried removing the library and then adding it, as well as changing the minSDK version back. Nothing has worked so far.

edit: I think removing the android-support-v4 from my custom library solved this.

Comment: there is a jar mismatch so you have two jar files with the same name. Remove the one of them and clean and build

Comment: Google updated their ADT plugin and crashed the build of library process. Follow these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Comment: if you have updated your adt to rev 22 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127.

Comment: Hmm... none of this has worked. I do have rev 22, but all projects already had "private libraries" checked. I also can't find two jar files with the same name, at least not in the same project. Am I not supposed to have android-support-v4 in my library project?