# Android Studio returning error "Unable to resolve superclass"

Tags: android, android-studio

I was able to solve the above error under Eclipse 4.2.2 by following instructions suggested by Raghunandan at:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after changing nothing in the project but upgrading eclipse android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127)

but I am now getting the same error under Android Studio but cannot apply the same solution as there is no 'Android Private Libraries' in the Java Build Path | Export Order tab.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if anyone's here for the anwser to this,
just delete the `build` folder & run