# Activity not found with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

Hi i've added the `AndroidAnnotations` and configured it; it generates the activity with the underscore `_` as suffix, but when I try to lunch the app, it gives this error

```
   05-26 04:17:23.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5096): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   Unable to instantiate activity
   ComponentInfo{android_app.candgo/android_app.candgo.HelloAndroidActivity_}:  
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
   "android_app.candgo.HelloAndroidActivity_"    
   on path: /data/app/android_app.candgo-1.apk
```

Any suggestion about why it doesn't work

PD: I've ADT v22
PD: I've the HelloAndroidActivity_ registered at manifest

This is my manifest.xml (sorry for the delay)

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity_">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the ".apt_generated", or whichever folder AA outputs to, to your source directories listing. In Android Studio, you can find this in Project Settings -> Modules -> module_in_question -> Sources

Comment: If this doesn't work, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you need to register the activity class(AndroidAnnotations) in your manifest.xml,like:
`<activity android:name = "com.your.packageName" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges = "orientation"/>`
then you can use it.

Comment: I had replaced that instead the original, adding the suffix _ to the manifest


And still doesn't work

Comment: maybe you need post your manifestxml content or screenshots,i'm sure there is something wrong in your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file for a entry of the activity. Check the name.

If you updated ADT to rev 22. you can try this [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after changing nothing in the project but upgrading eclipse android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127).

Check the package name in manifest

```
    <manifest package="com.example.mypackaganame" //check the name
```

Check under application tag for the activity entry

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mypackaganame.MainActivity"
        // this is the main activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Say you have second Activity. This how you declare for implicit intents

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.mypackaganame.SecondActivity"
        // this is the Second activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mypackaganame.SecondActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Foe explicit intents

```
      <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        // this is the Second activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Eclipse** follow these steps :

**Step 1.**
Go to `Java Compiler` and make sure that Compiler compliance level is set to 1.6, otherwise the processor won't be activated

**Step 2.**
Go to `Java Compiler` > `Annotation Processing` and choose **Enable annotation processing**

**step 3.**
Go to `Java Compiler` > `Annotation Processing` > `Factory Path` and add the processor JAR : **androidannotations-X.X.X.jar.**

**step 4**
Confirm the workspace rebuild