# Eclipse Refuses to create R.java file

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]I've run into a HUGE frustration. For some reason my Eclipse refuses to create my R.java file. I have read on the a few stackoverflow posts saying that I should use a clean and then build the project again. I have done this and still the problem is not rectified. I have even gone as far as deleting everything and then creating a brand new project and the same error persists, the R.java file is not created. Please please please can someone shed some light on this matter

I have read the link in the comments section below. Ive done as suggested and still nothing. Here is the code in my config.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="http://10.0.2.2:8080*" subdomains="true"/>
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin="*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this if you have updated adt to rev 22. R,java will not be generated if you have erros in your resources files. cross check once

Comment: I updated to revision 22 yesterday as I was asked to do this when I want to add the ADT plugin into eclipse

Comment: Follow the above link might help

Comment: if it helps let me know. if not i suggest you post some relevant code

Comment: It´s also possible that you have something wrong in any xml file. Check out all your xml files or post them here if there are not to much. For example, if You had any error inside and for some reason the R.java file was deleted, it doesn´t generate itself again until the error is fixed.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't complain about any errors in the system, but I will post up the xml file

Comment: @user1638809 is this a activity class? You post your code not he snap shot

Comment: Please elaborate further on what you mean by not setting the content to the activity

Comment: @user1638809 i suggest you post your whole code. its very difficult to spot the mistake in the snap shot. it's tiny

Comment: Simple solution - there must be an error in any of the in **res** folder.Check your console and you can see the error and Thank me later.