# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after ADT update

Tags: android

iam a beginner level programmer in android..Recently i have updated my ADT after that it showing an error in my project .Before this updation everthing was fine ..but now it showing following error which i copied from BOBcat...

```
05-27 09:38:58.046: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 09:38:58.046: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.newapp.freelanceeye.MainBase
```

but this Mainbase class is there in package

What will be the reason ...please someone help me

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. check this if you have updated adt to rev 22. this seems to be a common problem. Follow the link it should solve your problem

Comment: clean build restart then clean again and run!!