# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I am trying to show the date picker using Android-datepicker-Library( net.simonvt.app) library project in which Android-numberpicker-Library project is used which uses nineoldandroids-2.3.0.jar file. so the question is i am able to run the app on mac OS but not on windows 8 with same code. Application stops forcefully with showing Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I couldn't find the solution on this. Please help on this.

logcat shown bellow.

```
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample/com.sample.activity.v2.TimeBaseZomentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.sample.activity.v2.TimeBaseZomentActivity.onCreate(TimeBaseZomentActivity.java:76)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 11 more
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 22 more
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:174)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:147)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 25 more
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 32 more
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:669)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:532)
05-27 13:18:00.503: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  ... 35 more
```

Comment: did you update your adt to rev 22? If so check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: Looks like you have issues on the library import. Can you explain your project setup? So: Which IDE, which minsdk/maxsdk, on which device/emulator do you got this error, which android runs on it etc...

Comment: MyProject>Proprties>android> Add the Android-numberpicker-Library.
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
I was upadated my ADT to rev 22. and almost all the things are installed and updated without 3.x.
And this error got on any devices, i checked on ICS and Gingerbread

Comment: thanks Raghunandan, Its works for me