# getting actual position without showing Map

Tags: android

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

import android.location.Location;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mpv=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mpv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Obtention de la référence du service
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Si le GPS est disponible, on s'y abonne
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            abonnementGPS();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //On appelle la méthode pour se désabonner
        desabonnementGPS();
    }

    /**
     * Méthode permettant de s'abonner à la localisation par GPS.
     */
    public void abonnementGPS() {
        //On s'abonne
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);
    }

    /**
     * Méthode permettant de se désabonner de la localisation par GPS.
     */
    public void desabonnementGPS() {
        //Si le GPS est disponible, on s'y abonne
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        //On affiche dans un Toat la nouvelle Localisation
        final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("lat : ");
        msg.append(location.getLatitude());
        msg.append( "; lng : ");
        msg.append(location.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(this, msg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
        //Si le GPS est désactivé on se désabonne
        if("gps".equals(provider)) {
            desabonnementGPS();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
        //Si le GPS est activé on s'abonne
        if("gps".equals(provider)) {
            abonnementGPS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) { }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

but I receive an exception

```
05-27 09:23:53.266: E/AndroidRuntime(11369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmapsver2/com.example.gmapsver2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. if you have updated adt to rev 22

Comment: @Raghunandan: how is that related? I see another error in the post?

Comment: can you add your xml with the MapView?

Comment: MapView mpv=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map); this is the problem

Comment: @RvdK agreed. Din't check the post in full.  It should be GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                              .getMap(); instead of this MapView mpv=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

Comment: this is the layout.xml                                             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: do u need map or not?

Comment: @Ramzi try this GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); Also make sure you have added the support library.

Comment: I replace MapView by View and it works now thanks guys

Comment: @Naccer I want to send my location to a server using REST without showing the map