# R not generated in Actionbar sherlock 4.3.1

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I guess many SO users might have faced this same issue, as there are many questions on SO about this. 
I went through all the answers and checked for all the requirements, namely,

1. target sdk >
2. jdk 1.6
3. cleaning , restarting, reinstalling

I cant get the R file yet. Is there anything else I should check for? Help Jake Warton!

Comment: Have you deleted the `android-support-v4.jar` file withing your project itself? It's a possibility that it's cuz of conflicting `jar` files. I'm not sure if this is the cause for the missing `R.java` file.

Comment: I am only trying to get rid of the errors in Actionbarsherlock . I havent linked it to my project yet

Comment: I've actually had that error quite a few times. They used to get fixed randomly. Perhaps you should change your workspace?

Comment: Delete the gen folder and again buid the project, it may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. check this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open SDK manager and check if your Build Tools are updated

Comment: Put this in comment else we will DV you.

Comment: yep build tools are updated

Comment: oops... looks like ive got more updates to do

Comment: It seems no DV for me, even accepted answer @AndroidKiller :p

Answer (score 0):

No conclusion could be drawn from your description.

Yet here are some things that might be helpful.

1) Check Android SDK versions in the project property

2) Use "android tools->fix project property" to fix project setup

3) Project->clean

4) Have you ever changed the package name or class name within your android project? Be sure 
to use "android tools->rename" to do so.

Comment: did "android tools->fix project property"  ... nothing happened.

Comment: Where to check sdk version?

Comment: @user1840899 did you update adt to rev 22?. if so follow the link i posted above. You need to make sure you have checked android private libraries in your java build path under order export tab for both library project and your project.

Comment: I have only kept library project open ... I closed my own project. I thought i should make the library error free first

Comment: @user1840899 also make sure you have installed android sdk uild tools installed from the android sdk manager.Makes sure you follow both the suggested steps in the comment if you have updated adt to rev 22

Comment: @Raghunandan android libraries is checked already

Comment: @user1840899 I mean the same with Raghunandan.

Answer (score 0):

As far I Know Actionbarsherlock 4.3.1 requires **minimum 4.0** android version sdk to build actionbarsherlock library.check u have sdk version 4.0 in your eclipse.