# Getting error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" but the class is existing

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to figureout what is wrong with following code that is causing "class not found" exception but I am not able to solved it.

I am starting an activity that is extending MapActivity from mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar map quest library.

```
    public void onRoutePlanButtonClick(View v) {
        start = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.start)).getText().toString();
        destination = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.destination)).getText()
                .toString();

        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.setStart(start);
        driver.setDestination(destination);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverMap.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

the class DriverMap exists in com.thumbup.driver but the following code is causing the error

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverMap.class);
```

NOTES:

1. I made sure the map quest lib is on the correct path
2. When I call another Activity then it works without any problem
3. DriverMap extends ThumbUpMap implements ThumbUpLocationProvider
4. The activity that is calling DriverMap is storing some data locally, using SharedPreferences
5. I am using Android 2.3.3

Error from LogCat (adroid SDK):

```
06-03 14:29:24.558: E/dalvikvm(1979): Could not find class 'com.thumbup.driver.DriverMap', referenced from method com.thumbup.driver.Journey.onRoutePlanButtonClick
06-03 14:29:24.558: W/dalvikvm(1979): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 58 (Lcom/thumbup/driver/DriverMap;) in Lcom/thumbup/driver/Journey;
06-03 14:29:24.558: D/dalvikvm(1979): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0037
06-03 14:29:24.558: D/dalvikvm(1979): VFY: dead code 0x0039-003f in Lcom/thumbup/driver/Journey;.onRoutePlanButtonClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
06-03 14:29:38.238: D/AndroidRuntime(1979): Shutting down VM
06-03 14:29:38.238: W/dalvikvm(1979): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     ... 11 more
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.thumbup.driver.DriverMap
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.thumbup.driver.Journey.onRoutePlanButtonClick(Journey.java:32)
06-03 14:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     ... 14 more
```

**When I swtiched to Android 2.3.3, it is working! but not with 4.2.2**

Comment: updated adt to rev 22?

Comment: Did you ensure that mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar is included in your APK?

Comment: how you do that ? I am debugging on device

Comment: @Michael : Yes it is. It was working ok the problem started after I checked out on another machine

Comment: @amjad How do you build the APK (IDE like Eclipse, Ant, Maven)? Were the necessary build files also available on the other machine (or do you mean another Android device?) or did you recreate it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this if it helps. just a suggestion.

Comment: @Michael: I am using Eclipse it works when I am using Android 2.3.3 but not with 4.x.x.  I am running on android device (physical device).

Comment: BTW: Why I am getting penalty, is there anything wrong with the question :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Class not found suggests that your project cannot find the classes, probably because the .jar-file isn't included. Since you can call other activities I suppose that you haven't added the jar file properly.

Are you sure that the library is included in the build path?
Or, if you're not supposed to include it as a library, are you running an Android target instead of a Google target?

Try to fins the answer to one of the two above questions and the project will work!

Comment: I already tried both but not luck. Only switching to Android 2.3.3 works

Comment: What is the full name of the Driver-class? (With packages and all)