# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk

Tags: android, exception, applovin

Hi I get the following exception: `06-10 10:53:36.643: E/AndroidRuntime(10415): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk` I imported the external lib and also copy pasted the lib to /libs folder. but I still get this error. I imported the lib as : `import com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk;` and the program falls at this line : `AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);` . What am I missing?

lines before the error:

```
06-10 10:53:36.603: I/dalvikvm(10415): Could not find method com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk, referenced from method sk.wblade.psy.GalleryActivity.onCreate
06-10 10:53:36.603: W/dalvikvm(10415): VFY: unable to resolve static method 230: Lcom/applovin/sdk/AppLovinSdk;.initializeSdk (Landroid/content/Context;)V
06-10 10:53:36.603: D/dalvikvm(10415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
06-10 10:53:36.613: I/dalvikvm(10415): Could not find method com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialAd.show, referenced from method sk.wblade.psy.GalleryActivity.onResume
06-10 10:53:36.613: W/dalvikvm(10415): VFY: unable to resolve static method 229: Lcom/applovin/adview/AppLovinInterstitialAd;.show (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
06-10 10:53:36.613: D/dalvikvm(10415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0012
06-10 10:53:36.633: D/AndroidRuntime(10415): Shutting down VM
06-10 10:53:36.633: W/dalvikvm(10415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9b228)
```

Comment: did you update your adt to rev 22?

Comment: 22.0.1 is my current version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project right click properties-> Java BuildPath select Library and add external .jar the follow these step.

Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path than select Order and export tab. Set external .jar library checked and up it into top of the list. And clean and rebuild..It works for most of the cases

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in ADT 22. If you use this you have to check the Android Private Libraies in the Order and Export tab in Preferences/Java Build Path.

You can read about this in detail here:

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)