# Classnotfound exception while running the facebook sample app in android

Tags: android, facebook, classnotfoundexception

Trying with the facebook sdk and want to try running the sample app profilepicture .Follow all the step of configuration given in the facebook.developer official site .While import of the facebook sdk some error and exclaimation mark came but that thing are solved .But while running the simple app profilepicture some exception are showing on the logcat.here the details of the logcat with classnotfound exception:

```
06-10 18:06:48.039: I/Process(621): Sending signal. PID: 621 SIG: 9
06-10 18:08:22.509: W/dalvikvm(697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/facebook/samples/profilepicture/ProfilePictureSampleActivity; (59)
06-10 18:08:22.621: W/dalvikvm(697): Link of class 'Lcom/facebook/samples/profilepicture/ProfilePictureSampleActivity;' failed
06-10 18:08:22.621: D/AndroidRuntime(697): Shutting down VM
06-10 18:08:22.640: W/dalvikvm(697): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.samples.profilepicture/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
06-10 18:08:22.689: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  ... 11 more
```

so can anyone tell me what will be the solution for this exception.and this exception is coming for every sample app which came with the facebook sdk.Thanks for any hint.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020176/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-applovin-sdk-applovinsdk/17020252#17020252

Comment: have you add facebookloginActivity in your manifest?

Comment: thanks sunil your suggestion works....so upvote for u