# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker

Tags: android, static-libraries, android-videoview, vitamio

I used vitamio library to play videos, when I try to run this project, eclipse returns this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker

That is issue, if you have any idea then please share it with me.

Comment: try to add in order and export to this extrenal jar file try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020176/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-applovin-sdk-applovinsdk/17020252#17020252

Comment: @sunil i have added library project from property-> Android -> added library project.

Comment: if you updated sdk with adt  rev 22? then need to checked the check box of this jar file with order and export option. And then clean and build the project

Answer (score 0):

download vitamio.jar file from vitamioLib and buildit