# the following class could not be found android.support.v7.internal.app.windowDecoration

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i just setup the android studio (**version 1.5**)  on my mac for each time i create a new project same error appear

> the following class could not be found android.support.v7.internal.app.windowDecoration

i just tried every solution mentioned here but same problem persist

have a nice day

[The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742114/rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-v7), [ERROR :rendering problems The following classes could not be found android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo), and [Error: "The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" after upgrading Android SDK Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430607/error-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-v7-widget-gr)

Answer (score 1):

solve the problem by this way:

1. Import support library as a project from "sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat".
2. Reference library in your project (for Eclipse, "Properties - Android - Add").
3. Build projects (for Eclipse, "Projects - Build All"). Make sure, you have "android.support.v7.appcompat" in your main project gen folder.
4. If it doesn't worked - clean and rebuild project.