# Finding Current Location and navigate to it not working

Tags: android, android-mapview

Hi i just develop a app that is to find current location and navigate to current location.
i am running it on real device but getting an error that "unfortunately current location has stopped". why i am getting this error when everything is correct...????
how can i overcome it....
Regards

Main activtiy code

```
package com.example.routetracker;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GoogleMap map;
LocationManager lm;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
             .getMap();
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

     LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

     @Override
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
     Bundle extras) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     (int) (location.getLatitude() + location.getLongitude()),
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
     .title("my position")
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
     .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
     location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15.0f));

     }
     };
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

     }

     }
```

Manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.routetracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission     
 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.routetracker.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.routetracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.routetracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
              <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDizP29Y9VGJmDlGR-po6p0gzuXVuKEFCo" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051160/exception-when-running-google-map-v2-application/17051230#17051230. Since your min sdk is 8 you should use `SupportMapFragment` and your class must extend `FragmentActivity`. Use `MapFragment` for api 12 and above

Comment: i changed min sdk to 12, but still getting same issue

Comment: post the stack trace its a crash and that was one of the issues you corrected now