# R file not generated

Tags: android, eclipse

I know many similar questions have been asked for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) one. Mine is slightly different. I create a new android project using all the default settings (target SDK 4.2 Jelly Bean, min SDK 2.2 Froyo). The project is created without an R file. I tried cleaning the project and nothing happens. I tried looking for errors in the res folder and nothing happened. All my XML file names are lower case. What could I have messed up to cause brand new projects to not generate R files? Is there some Eclipse configuration that needs fixing? Is there some Android module that I haven't installed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you recently update your ADT ?

Comment: did you update your adt?

Comment: Have you installed ADT plugin? If yes, reinstall and try

Comment: Yes I updated my ADT this morning

Comment: Re-open the SDK manager and check if all is installed/updated

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have **android sdk build tools** installed from the sdk manager if you have updated adt to rev 22 
Install it resart the eclipse and make clean and rebuild project it will work

Comment: Yes I see that the build tools is out of date, I'll update it and see if that works. Thanks.