# what is the procedure for generating R.java in android Eclipse juno

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have installed eclipse juno and also added the plugin's of the android sdk. After installing android SDK manager, I've created a new android project, but a problem arises in `R.java` file. `R.java` doesn't open. Please give me a solution. I am new to android.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the problems tab of eclipse? If yes, then please post the details.

Comment: clean and rebuild ur projrct

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086013/r-file-not-generated/17086081#17086081

Comment: yes. it is adt rev 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have **Android SDK Build-Tools** installed from the **Android SDK Manager**

Click this guy:

[image]

Then make sure the top three are all installed:

[image]

Comment: how to open Android SDK Build-Tools?

Comment: Open Android SDK Manager to check the status of Android SDK Build-tools.

Comment: Thank you. i made a problem on installing Android SDK Build-Tools.  Now the problems are solved.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Project -> Build Project

**Edit**

1. Remove your `gen` directory and `bin` directory
2. Click on Project -> Clean (wait till cleaning complete)
3. Click Project -> Build Project

Comment: i tried. but i have still error in lines corresponding R.java file and R.java not generated

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the code, resources and AndroidManifest.xml do not have any problem.

First, delete the R.java file. As soon as you delete, that file should be re-generated automatically if you have enabled automatic build (*Project->Build Automatically*).

If that doesn't work try to clean the project by clicking on *Project->Clean*.

If it still doesn't work then, confirm you have android sdk build tools installed. For this, open Android SDK Manager and ensure **Android SDK Build-tools** has the status of **Installed**.

Also confirm that the ADT is up-to-date. To update ADT, in eclipse go to:
 *Help -> Check for updates*. Select the necessary entries like: Android Development Tools and update them.

Hopefully one of these solutions will solve your problems :-).

Comment: Thank you. i made a problem on installing Android SDK Build-Tools.  Now the problems are solved.