# I have updated SDK.R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-tools

I have updated SDK for the latest but still I am getting this error .R cannot be resolved to a variable. I know its not generating R.java. what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: have u updated your ADT revision?

Comment: Restart eclipse and then clean your project!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162479/what-is-the-procedure-for-generating-r-java-in-android-eclipse-juno/17162535#17162535. try this

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961/2345913) and then ofcourse try clean build your project..

Comment: @Michael Shrestha YES i HAVE UPDATED IT TO LATEST adt 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your `Platform-Tools` and install `Android Build tools` too...

and restart your eclipse... 
hope this helps..
check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584015/java-eclipse-no-more-r-file-ever/16584243#16584243) for more info..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Java code is correct, most likely your cause is an error in a `resource` or your `AndroidManifest.xml` file that is preventing R.java from being regenerated. To figure out what is going on:

1. Look for red X marks in the Package Explorer for resources or the
   manifest
2. Look in the Console for error messages
3. Look in the Problems view for error messages

**Refer this for other solutions:** [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score -1):

Delete R.java file from your source folder. Now Clean your project Click on **Project** >> **Clean** >> **Clean Project selected below** >> Select **your project** from list >> **ok**.

and also try this.

Right Click on your **Projectname** >> **Android Tools** >> **Fix project Property**

Comment: its not generating R.java.