# Can't run the project after updating the android ADT bundle and Google play services library

Tags: android

I have updated the latest ADT bundle and google play services library. After that I tried to run the previously working project. But this time can't run at the device.
Messages at the LogCat are shown as follow. What is wrong and which part I am missing to run the previous project?

```
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sg.SanThit.TrackMe/sg.SanThit.TrackMe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sg.SanThit.TrackMe.MainActivity
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sg.SanThit.TrackMe.MainActivity
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
06-15 13:36:32.785: E/AndroidRuntime(30862):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: On the last ADT update I had a similar issue, I had to check for updates (both in the SDK manager and in Eclipse under Help) a couple of times til neither showed any updates, clean the project, and close and re-open Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127 try this

Comment: Yeah after cleaning the project, close and re-open the eclipse. It worked. Thanks