# Android: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

Ok, I know there are several questions like this, but I've been through all of them and nothing seems to work! I have been using eclipse for almost a year now. I installed new softwares from the Help menu, and since then nothing is working! I re-installed eclipse and now I'm getting this "R cannot be resolved to a variable", even when I create a brand new project. Here's the code:

```
package test.pro;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am getting an error in the setContentView and getMenuInflater lines. I looked in the 'gen' folder, there's nothing there! I also checked the Java Build Path, it's fine. The ADT is updated. Can someone help me out here!!? I really need it!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: you have to import it ctrl + shitf + o in eclipse

Comment: I had this problem once after updating the ADT, turns out the first set of updates were incomplete. So try re-running the ADT updater a few times, restarting eclipse in between?

Comment: I tried organizing the imports, didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you have specifically checked and installed "Android SDK Build-Tools" from the SDK Manager.

Comment: if you add string recently check if it dont include ' (Apostrophe), if you find  Apostrophe remove it...

Comment: SDK Build Tools was not installed. I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is because of some error in layout, strings, dimensions or any other xml file. Look for such xml error, resolve it and you should be good to go.
Also do perform a clean of your project. This error is very common with me too.

Comment: _I'm getting this "R cannot be resolved to a variable", even when I create a **brand new project**._ So I don't think there is a problem with the xml files but more with the ADT update

Comment: It is an empty project, all it has is the default basic code. And cleaning didn't work either.

Comment: Did you install ADT from market place? If yes then install it using Install New Software feature and adding that URL for android ADT plugin (just google install ADT plugin). The Eclipse marketplace plugin is buggy.