# Google map api v2 error = Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: android

While trying to use google maps encountered this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{bm.abc.swip/bm.abc.swip.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bm.abc.swip.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/bm.abc.swip-2.apk]
```

Comment: try this similar uestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127