# Pack Android Custom View in jar file

Tags: android, android-view

Is there a way to create a custom Android view with all its necessary stuff (source code, layout file, defined attributes, ...) and pack it as a JAR file?

Comment: no you cannot package resources into jars. you can package pure a java classes that do not refer to resources as jar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290868/is-it-possible-to-add-a-jar-file-of-a-library-project-and-use-its-resources-in-a/17291460#17291460

Comment: you can make one project library project and  reference the same in others like google play services library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565865/android-use-activity-in-jar-noclassdeffounderror#comment25556528_17565865. check this. might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not possible to package resource file in Jar.
Instead you can make your view project as a library project and refer it from your actual project.