# Updated eclipse, every single project broken

Tags: android, eclipse

http://puu.sh/3oa21.png

See above, 119 errors in total, every single project has been broken and everything is undefined, including inconsistent 'hierarchys of type'new projects dont have this problem.. :/ at my last tether please help!

http://puu.sh/3oa21.png

Comment: try restarting eclipse

Comment: tried that countless times, including cleans and re imports

Comment: @Broak try this if you have updated adt to rev 22. not sure if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Answer (score 1):

Updating my ADT helped me when I had the same problem:

How to Update your ADT to Latest Version

- In Eclipse go to Help
- Install New Software ---> Add
- inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or whatever you want) and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- after loading you should get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
- check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or check Developer Tool only
- click Next
- Finish

Edit:
Did you try restarting your PC? adb.exe (and maybe other background services) might need to be restarted

Comment: Updated to the latest ADT, still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at your build path for your project you will probably see errors in it right?

What you need to do it change the order of the build path and make sure all boxes are checked.

I had to change my order to `src/Android Private Libraries/SDK version/Android Dependencies/gen` in that order

see here also

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Comment: still change the order because those errors look similar to errors I had when I updated to the new ADT

Comment: you might also have to delete libraries and re-add them. I had to completely remove all my libraries from disk and download and re-add them again

Comment: Absolutely NOTHING works, i even tried copying all the files into a new project, same errors.