# Facebook integration android support v4 content localBroadcastManager

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Im trying to deal with a facebook integration login for my simple android application. Im following this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ and everthing seems to go fine, but am still gettin exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

I know there are alot similar questions about this problem like this [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after changing nothing in the project but upgrading eclipse android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra) 
that says that I must check all the checkboxes in java build path in Other and export tab but Ive done it already and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue and scoured the internet for solutions.  I read many of the suggestions posted in answers like the one you linked and none of them seemed to work.  I ended up getting it to work.  My issue was that I had misunderstood several of the other posts.  I thought that when they said *"make sure android-support-v4.jar was in your libs folder"* they were referring to the android-support-v4.jar in the FacebookSDK project.

Once I added android-support-v4.jar to my project and followed the other suggestions related to Order and Export.  After cleaning and rebuilding the project it no longer crashed.  Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem and solved it. I copied and pasted myproject's android-support-v4.jar into Facebook SDK's lib folder. That makes it work.