# Android Fragment integeration/path Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater, android-support-library

Am using fragment for commonly used UI elements . Implemented a simple POC to check and its working cool . But when am integerating to my main project it giving run time error(crash)

here is my Androidmainfiest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.draw.map.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My fragment xml:fragment_text_view_bottom_slider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/register_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/register_inner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/slider_button"
                android:background="#ECEDF2"
                android:onClick="goToProfile"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="goToProfile"
                    android:src="@drawable/dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_block"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dummy_image" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/bottom_slider_register1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_text2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/register_text1"
                        android:text="@string/bottom_slider_register2" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlSlideAlert"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/slider_button"
                android:background="#ECEDF2"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#50555C"
                    android:gravity="right" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_slider_alert_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="WEH is totally blocked"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/slider_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="slideButtonOnClick"
                        android:src="@drawable/alert_1" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/slider_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="slideButtonOnClick"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/register_main"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="goToProfile"
                android:src="@drawable/dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="reportOnClick"
                android:src="@drawable/report" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/route_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/route_tapover" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/more" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/other_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="closeBottomMenu"
                android:src="@drawable/close_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment java file: TextViewBottomSlider.java

```
public class TextViewBottomSlider extends Fragment{

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_view_bottom_slider, 
                                 container, false);
      // intilizeUIElements();
        return view;
   }
}
```

my activity xml: activity_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_slider_fragment"
        android:name="com.draw.map.TextViewBottomSlider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_text_view_bottom_slider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity file:TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

}
```

my logcat:

```
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.draw.map/com.draw.map.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at com.draw.map.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:12)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     ... 11 more
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.draw.map-1.apk]
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
08-24 06:05:12.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5355):     ... 20 more
```

Have other library files included in my project:
* facebook android SDK
* google play service
* android support jar 4

Thanks for your time

Comment: first check that "TextViewBottomSlider" class is in com.draw.map package...

Comment: yes its in draw.map package

Comment: what is your min sdk? and post the full manifest

Comment: Ok...Then have you add android.support.v4 jar file in your project?

Comment: Min SDK:8 compliling on 4.2 android version . Am using google maps (which also works on fragment principle) without any issue

Comment: But you are calling simple fragment rather than Google Map??

Comment: have android.support.v4 jar in libs folder .

Comment: and also include as a reference dependency..

Comment: @PiyushGupta Maps i have implemented in the same project and working cool . Now in my project i need to make some fragment for common reusable UI component . This were am getting this issue .

Comment: @BasavarajHampali i don't see you using map fragment you should use `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: if you want to use google Map then you should give a name of that map class name

Comment: @Raghunandan  this is my map fragment     <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraZoom="13"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true" /> dont miz map issue with the present one

Comment: @BasavarajHampali it seems you have a problem in your build path . try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: @Raghunandan when had updated new tools had the same issue and had checked "private lib" in order and export . From ur link one thing is missing from my end . Android build tools not installed am installing it

Comment: @Raghunandan but strongly feel "Android build tools" is not the problem . as am able to run the same code in other project

Comment: @BasavarajHampali in that case check your import statements.

Comment: Strongly feel the real culprit is facebook SDK 3.0 . It also includes support library, may be some conflicting happening

Comment: @BasavarajHampali could be if there is a conflict remove the jar that is duplicate from your libs folder

Comment: @Raghunandan and others thanks for help. Issue was http://stackoverflow.com/a/18417215/1506239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check your import statements.**

As you said your MIN SDK vesion is 8.

**Theses statements will not work ;**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

**To Fragment support from SDK vesion is 8 you need to import these statements**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```