# Fragment instantiation exception in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Trying place `fragment` container and `Mapfragment` in single layout getting above error.
here placing xml file (start.xml). And from my java class `setContentviw(R.layout.start)`.

stacktrace shows that

> error in declaring map fragment

didn't get it.help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

logs

```
09-26 01:59:05.654: E/dalvikvm(1821): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment', referenced from method com.tukutane.StartActivity.initilizeMap
09-26 01:59:05.654: W/dalvikvm(1821): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 396 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;) in Lcom/tukutane/StartActivity;
09-26 01:59:05.664: D/dalvikvm(1821): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
09-26 01:59:05.854: D/AndroidRuntime(1821): Shutting down VM
09-26 01:59:05.854: W/dalvikvm(1821): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tukutane/com.tukutane.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at com.tukutane.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:34)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     ... 11 more
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     ... 22 more
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tukutane-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tukutane-1, /system/lib]]
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
09-26 01:59:05.974: E/AndroidRuntime(1821):     ... 25 more
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tukutane"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >

    <!-- Added SplashActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tukutane.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Adding MainActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tukutane.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Adding StartActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tukutane.StartActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Adding LoginActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tukutane.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Adding RegistrationActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tukutane.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.integratingfacebook.UserDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/maps_key" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity

```
 package com.tukutane;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.tukutane.R.drawable;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    public static Context appContext;
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        // ActionBar
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Setting resource for tab

        ActionBar.Tab ProfileTab = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(drawable.profile);
        ActionBar.Tab SettingsTab = actionbar.newTab()
                .setIcon(drawable.setting);

        ActionBar.Tab MessagesTab = actionbar.newTab()
                .setIcon(drawable.message);
        ActionBar.Tab ContactsTab = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(
                drawable.contacts);
        ActionBar.Tab DropDownTab = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(drawable.menu);

        Fragment ProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Fragment SettingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        Fragment MessagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
        Fragment ContactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
        Fragment DropdownFragment = new DropdownFragment();

        // Setting Tab Listener
        ProfileTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(ProfileFragment));
        SettingsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(SettingsFragment));
        MessagesTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(MessagesFragment));
        ContactsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(ContactsFragment));
        DropDownTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(DropdownFragment));

        actionbar.addTab(ProfileTab);
        actionbar.addTab(SettingsTab);
        actionbar.addTab(MessagesTab);
        actionbar.addTab(ContactsTab);
        // actionbar.addTab(DropDownTab);
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_search:
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "suggest places and events",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menuitem_add:
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menuitem_share:
            TextView inf = new TextView(this);
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CharSequence[] items = { "Invite friends", "Suggestions", "Points" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (item == 0) {

                    } else if (item == 1) {

                    } else if (item == 2) {

                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow()
                    .getAttributes();

            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
            wmlp.x = 50; // x position
            wmlp.y = 75; // y position

            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.appContext, "Reselected!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your activity code and manifest

Comment: change your min sdk to 12 and post your activity as a part of your question not as an answer

Comment: also have you referenced google play services library project in your androoid project?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: problem in xml file yar ,declaring those fragments is wrong,please check it.i am not getting what is problem.

Comment: did you change your min sdk to 12 and try?

Comment: how did you refer to your library project? not sure check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127 coz there might be problem with your build path "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path:.."

Comment: No issues with buildpath.

Comment: there may be coz you get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` you might have not configured your build path properly.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

replace with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: there is no need for that coz you can change your min sdk to 12. hardly devices run on api 11 according to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. Even if its 11 then  she needs to change `MapFrament` to `SupportMapFragment` extend `FragmentActivity` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`